# Compare all rows in a MySQL Table

Tags: mysql

For example I have a row with numbers:

```
id   number
1    5
2    72
3    14
4    72
5    16
6    5
7    14
8    5
```

I would like MySQL to start looking from row 1 and decide if it's row "number" exists (one or more times) or not in the whole table. After that, it should check the second row, etc.

In this example it should first search for number "5" and it should let me know that there are more than 1 occurrence, than go to the second row and check 72, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT number, count(1) as cnt FROM table GROUP BY number HAVING cnt > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

what's the desired end result? if to find which "number"s occur more than once then simple "group by" on it with count will do

```
select number, count(1) from mytable group by number
```

add "having" to show only those with count(1) > 1

Answer (score 0):

You want to group by.  Like this:

```
    Select number, count(number) 
    From table_name
    group by number
```